# Best approach to store logged in User Id

Tags: java, jsf

I have small application using JSF 1.1. It is using NTLM for authentication.

What is the best approach to store the logged in user_id, so that could be used in application across all java classes, user_id would be used in almost all jsf pages corresponding java classes.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it in the web session :

```
session=FacesContext.getExternalContext().getSession();
session.setAttribute("user_id",user_id);
```

Comment: In order to call this session value in all beans where I need to write it to database or for any other purpose, do I need to put in some common classes in my application so that it could be referred from anywhere?

Comment: yes maybe have a Context class that have a static method getContextSession() that would return your session object : Context.getContextSession()

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on how you are performing authentication. If you are delegating the authentication process to the container, by using FORM, BASIC or DIGEST authentication, then you can obtain the `Principal` object associated with the current request using the following snippet:

```
Principal user = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

The name of the user in the realm can be obtained using the `user.getName()` method. Under the hood, the container stores the Principal object in the `HttpSession` instance, but this is not accessible as an attribute using the `HttpSession.getAttribute(...)` method, in most containers.

The Principal object is also automatically propagated by the Servlet container to the EJB container, when the business method of an EJB is invoked, and you can access it using the `SessionContext` interface. In an EJB, you can perform the following, to obtain a reference to the Principal:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;

public void businessMethod()
{
    Principal user = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
    ...
}
```

If you are not delegating authentication to the container, and instead, you are performing authentication using your own scheme, then you must store the reference to the identity of the user in the HttpSession object upon successful authentication, and you must clear this upon session invalidation. Storing it in other scopes is not recommended, as only a HttpSession object has the same lifetime as a user's session with the application.

Comment: I wouldn't be using EJB's. Could you kindly provide some sample on how to store on HTTPSession object?

Comment: @Polappan, it's provided in the other answer.